# HTML CSS: How to Make Div Box Height Equal Text Height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this example,
how do I make the height of the div box equal height of the font text (regardless if I change font-size in the future)? The div box should basically be wrapping the text. Right now I see extra space? I tried padding 0px, margin 0px, but did not work. You can Ctrl-shift-i the code snippet below in Chrome

(extra padding seen here, trying to get rid of it)

[image]

```css
div {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
   

<div class="card-title cardtext">Header Title</div>
```

Comment: `line-height:1` ?

Comment: I feel like, 

a) You have left some code out or 
b) What you actually have highlighted is the html tag and not the div

Because by default the div should already be 'wrapping' the text.

Comment: Where is the CSS in question?

Comment: For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing your after: https://jsfiddle.net/jkyg40hm/

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-title cardtext">
  <p>Header Title</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
 position: relative;
 display: block;

 height: auto;
 width: auto;

 background-color: #000;
}

p{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  color: #fff;

  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;

  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: the height of the box has to match the height of font, plus it has to account for variable font sizes

Comment: @jerrythomas sorry i knew that just slipped my mind lol edit made.

Comment: well if you adjust the font size, its bigger, additionally line height has to be variable, trying to refrain from fixed pixel sizes, if I have variable font sizes

Comment: Cool in that case use % instead of px for the line-height for example: 70%

Comment: thanks its seems to be working more, how did you get line height .7, was it in a book?

Comment: I used the Chrome Dev tools and made live edits till i found a value that worked